# How to hide the selected layer in Photoshop using Keyboard? Is there any shortcut?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I searched it all around the web but I didn't find. Is there any keyboard shortcut to hide/show the selected layer in photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

I have never known a shortcut for what you are asking for, but here is a link that shows all the [**Keys for the Layers panel**](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html#keys_for_the_layers_panel) and a list for all [**Default keyboard shortcuts**](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html) in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom keyboard shortcut that is based on the menu; *Layer -> Hide layer/Show layer*; For me I set the keyboard shortcut to **CTRL + Alt + H** (previously set to *view -> show -> target path*, which i never used!).

To create a keyboard shortcut go to; *Edit -> Keyboard shortcuts*

Answer (score 0):

This is a funky work-around, but you can always hit "1" and make the layer 10% opacity which hides it for all practical purposes.